# What is the alternative of all the deprecated methods of BackendService Interface(Google AppEngine)

Tags: google-app-engine

Could you please suggest what method to use instead as all the methods of BackendService Interface(Google AppEngine) are deprecated.

Reference url :
[Deprecated methods of BankendService Interface](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/backends/BackendService)

Answer (score 0):

Backends as a whole is deprecated. You should move over to [modules](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/modules/).